# I can not download file via ajax in spring mvc without save file in server

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

In a one page a have a link to download a file like `\myapp\controller\file?id=45`

In controller have

```
        InputStream stream = null;          
        byte [] buffer =someService.getFile(somedata); 
        stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
        System.out.println("get file---");
         response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=report.pdf");

        try {
            IOUtils.copy(stream, response.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("get file---OK");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This work well, but in another page

```
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '${url}',                  
                data: {sdate: $('#date').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data)                     
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log("in error");
                } 
            });
```

In console ever say

> get file---
>
> get file---OK

**but the browser does nothing.**

I add in succes `alert(data)` to debug, it shows the binary content of PDF file like:

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <>stream x�͝O�$�q���)ޑ:��U]���E�d�A��1^h��ǃ\nS��#��������?���X+��RI��J����Y�r��F�?

Now, how explorer understand is a file to download?

**For lack of permits, i can not save files server side**

Comment: Do you able to download file using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use ajax to download files.

Either use

- Jquery ajax file download plugin http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/
- or generate the file on server side pass the url using ajax and 
  use `window.location="fileName"`

Comment: i can´t generate file in server. So i have to test the plugin, thanks